# List Of errors in the modelState

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to see all the errors of the ModelState in the Quick of visual studio without writing any codes like :

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
        DoSomethingWith(error);
    }
```

i'm looking for something

```
ModelSate.Errors
```

Thanks.

Comment: what actually do you want???

Comment: you could always write `public List<ModelError> GetErrors()` in `ModelState` to do this exact thing in "one line". what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Exception,the best way to get all the erros of the ModelState

Comment: No thing is wrong in my code, is there any way to get all the error of the ModelStae without writing the code above, i just want see the errors in Quick watch

Comment: If you add `ModelState` to Watch, you can expand `Values` and inspect the error(s) of each value, but its probably easier to do what you doing now.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, i know i can do that, but if i have 100 values, i'll not check each value to see if there is an error or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a string of errors as shown :

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
  string desc = "";
  foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) { 
    desc = desc + " ," + error.ErrorMessage.ToString();  //here 'error.ErrorMessage' will have required error message
    //DoSomethingWith(error.ErrorMessage.ToString());
   }
}
```

As shown above **'error.ErrorMessage'** will have error message not **'error'**(questioner used only 'error' in the question).

Comment: Thanks for responding, my question was if is there any way to get the list of the errors without writing code, some object provided by mvc, some thinglike Object.Errors

Comment: @BilelChaouadi...no this is the best and straight forward method to get error message..

Comment: @Exception: this is not an anwser. you have just rewrite his code.

Comment: @AmitKumar..just see carefully...its different and moreover a have created a string of all error messages...

Comment: @Exception: where you are seeing difference . he is already written DoSomethingWith(error). 
he want to know any other method to get error. he already written that loop in his code. SEE CAREFULLY .

Comment: @AmitKumar....'error.ErrorMessage' will have error message not 'error'...see the questioner is only using 'error'

Comment: ok thank you,if this is the best way i'll do it.